# Where are detailed results of New York State elections available?

Tags: united-states, election, new-york

Where can I find published the official election results for New York State (USA)?

We just had an election which included many NY State offices (as well as federal US) but their results are very hard to find.

- BallotPedia has federal results, and information about the state
  election, but no results.
- Googling for terms like "NY state senate elections 2018" returns
  results for the NY senators to the federal government, which is
  entirely different.
- I have found news articles that describe in general terms the
  election results - e.g., that the NY Senate now has a majority of
  Democrats - but not a specific breakdown of the exact results,
  district by district.

This may well be a problem for other US states also, so if there is any single source which is comprehensive for all of them that would be a bonus.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of the 7th November 2018 it seems very probable the final certified results from yesterday's election aren't out yet (it appears that this can take up to 25 days), but does the following page of uncertified results from the [New York State Board of Elections Election Night Reporting Page](http://www.elections.ny.gov/ENR/NYSENRAccessible.html) serve your purposes?

I found this via the [New York General Election page](http://www.thegreenpapers.com/G18/NY) at thegreenpapers.com, which I'd suggest as a good aggregator for election results in the US.

Comment: That seems to be just what I had in mind, thank you!  Will the certified results ultimately appear in the same location?

Comment: @DaveInCaz As in somewhere on http://www.elections.ny.gov? Yes. As in that specific link, that bit I'm less certain of.